# Microsoft Azure Failed to connect via ssh

Tags: php, azure, ubuntu, ssh, ufw

I have created an instance in microsoft azure, Install Apache, PHP , Mysql etc.
Installation done using putty. After installation I was abruptly run UFW, **sudo ufw enable** After that I cannot connect my server via SSH. How to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, it seems that you didn't set the ufw rules for allowing some ports, such as port 22 for SSH, port 80 for Apache and port 3306 for MySQL. So after you were enable the ufw, the SSH connection was refused by the ufw.

Unfortunately, I think you need to delete the current instance and create a new instance on Azure.

Then, please make sure the allow rules for SSH has been added before enabling the ufw.

For more helpful tutorial, please see the wiki page at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.